# DART - how to combine two different Future based queries?

Tags: dart, rxdart

I have a Flutter form that will require data from two different sources, i.e.

```
class DataForForm {
   MasterData master;
   List<Transaction> transactions;
}
```

One query will bring back 'master data', and a second query will bring back 'transaction data'.

How can I build a 'Future' call that will wait for both queries to execute, and for the results to be returned in the aggregated 'DataForForm' class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Future<DataForForm> getData(...) async {
  MasterData masterData = await getMasterData(...);
  List<Transaction> transactions = await getTransactions(...);
  return DataForm(master: masterData, transactions: transactions);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but with your sample code the two queries will run one after the other. Is there a way to have both executed in parallel? Like 'Future.wait'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? One of these both queries has to be performed before the other one. Future.wait does the same just for a list of futures instead of two.

Comment: Oops, my assumption was that 'wait' would execute each query in a separate thread, Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, thats wrong. "async, await" still *runs* in the same thread. If you really need multiple threads, then have a look at **Isolates**. Please accept and vote up the answer if it helped you. Feel free to ask if you still have questions.